# iter_swap yields wrong result

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void myfunction(int i)
{
    cout<<" "<<i;
};

void multiply(int a)
{
    a*2;
}

int main()
{
     int t[]={10,5,9,6,2,4,7,8,3,1};
    vector<int> v1(t,t+10);
    for_each(v1.begin(),v1.end(),multiply);
    iter_swap(v1.begin(), t+9);
    for_each(v1.begin(),v1.end(),myfunction);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Hello, I actually have question about this code.
when I run this, I see the result is **1 5 9 6 2 4 7 8 3 1** and I am not sure why the last element is still 1 even though I assigned the statement `iter_swap(v1.begin(), t+9);` in the middle.

Comment: The function `multiply()` has no effect.   The effect of changing an argument that is passed by value is invisible to the caller.

Comment: Sure, `multiply` does nothing useful, but that's not what the question is about.  Also, changing the argument to a reference would not be enough, if the intention is to actually modify the value.  The function would need to do something like `a *= 2;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `iter_swap(v1.begin(), t+9);`, you're swapping the 1st element of the `std::vector` `v1` and the 10th element of the array `t`. `v1` and `t` are two independent objects. And you're printing out the elements of `v1` as `for_each(v1.begin(),v1.end(),myfunction);`, but the 10th element of `v1` is not changed.

You might want

```
iter_swap(v1.begin(), v1.end()-1); // swap the 1st and 10th element of v1
for_each(v1.begin(),v1.end(),myfunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looked through your code and the output is correct,

```
for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), multiply);
```

The output for the code above is v1 = 10,5,9,6,2,4,7,8,3,1 while
t is also the same t = 10,5,9,6,2,4,7,8,3,1

```
 iter_swap(v1.begin(), t + 9);
```

When you swap `v1.begin` and `t+9` u are swapping `10 in v1` with `1 in t9` hence the final output

```
1 5 9 6 2 4 7 8 3 1
```

You can try swapping the first and last elements.

```
iter_swap(v1.begin(), v1.end()-1); 
for_each(v1.begin(),v1.end(),myfunction);
```